# How to change the heap size of standalone Master's JVM?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using Spark 1.4.0. My spark master JVM experienced an OOM error so I'd like to increase master's heap size. I'm wondering how to specify it correctly?

I tried the following, but it failed and the JVM is still running with the default value:

```
spark-env.sh
export SPARK_MASTER_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms1g -Xmx1g"
```

Comment: When you are getting OOM error at trying to start your cluster or any spark application.

Comment: Are you using spark-submit to start the application? If so you can set it with the option `--driver-memory`

Answer (score 4):

Use `SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY` to increase heap size, i.e. `-Xms` and `-Xmx` options. It is `1g` by default.

Use `SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS` for JVM options for the Spark master and worker daemons themselves in the form `-Dx=y` (default: none).

Use `SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND` to see the entire command line for a Spark script.